# setting up JSON format link

Tags: android

I'm trying to setup a json format link so I can parse. does this format look right to you guys?

```
{"suspended": "false","firstName": "John","lastName": "Smith","checkedin": 0,"checkindatetime": 0,"address": {"streetAddress": "21 2nd Street","city": "New York","state": "NY","postalCode": "10021"},"phoneNumber": [{ "type": "home", "number": "212 555-1234" },{ "type": "fax", "number": "646 555-4567" }]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is valid JSON - You can use [this](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate it